# Figure out the list of 10 words

Tags: word, word-sequence

For this puzzle, you must figure out a list of 10 words.

Each of the following words is a clue for a word in the list:

- Candy
- Jack
- Following
- Territory
- Area
- Common
- Improve
- Straight
- Membrane
- Leg

The clues are in order, so Candy is a clue for the first word in the list, Jack is a clue for the second word in the list, and so on.  The list of 10 words has some sort of relationship between all the words.

I have structured this puzzle so that there is only one perfect answer.

Hints:

> 1. Some of the clues are synonyms, but not all of them are.
>
> 2. I would start with the third through eighth clues, since the other 4 are a little more difficult.
>
> 3. See [my comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/figure-out-the-list-of-10-words#comment16736_5510) to dmg's answer.
>
> 4. The first word is a specific type, and the second word is not a synonym.

Comment: Do the words relate to each other in any way?

Comment: Like I said, there is *some sort* of a relationship. ;-)

Comment: Sorry I just completely missed that

Comment: The word dog appears in my head when I read that list.

Comment: "I have structured this puzzle so that there is only one perfect answer." - but how should I know if what I've got is "perfect"? - what does "perfect" mean? May I guess that it means that we are looking for a grammatical or famous sentence or something? :)

Comment: @d'alar'cop I suppose it's theoretically possible for someone to come up with a really good answer different from mine. In that case maybe I'll just accept it without mentioning mine. ;-)  But no, it's not a sentence.  Just a bunch of words that when put in a certain order reveal a relationship.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I all but guarantee this is not the "perfect" answer,  but I would say it would qualify as an answer...

> Candy - IceBreakers (A specific type of candy)
> Jack - Ma (Jack Ma is a Chinese entrepreneur and philanthropist.)
> Following - Pursuing
> Territory - Enclave
> Area - Compass
> Common - Conventional
> Improve - Advance
> Straight - Beeline
> Membrane - Lamina
> Leg - Extremity (a leg is an extremity)
>
> 1 is a type of candy, 2 is NOT a synonym, and some of my answers are synonyms I got from thesaurus.com (3 through 9) so it meets the requirements for hints 1-4.
>
> So what do the answers have in common? The first letters of the answers spell "Impeccable" which is a synonym of "Perfect"

Comment: The only quibble I have is that Ice Breakers candy is two words, not one.  But I love how you spelled out IMPECCABLE, so I will accept your answer.  Great job!  :)

Comment: Yeah, well... I made the mistake of starting from the bottom and by the time I got to 'i' I felt I had to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer that I had in mind:

> `Candy     - Jellybean`
>
> `Jack      - Beanstalk`
>
> `Following - Stalking`
>
> `Territory - Kingdom`
>
> `Area      - Domain`
>
> `Common    - Mainstream`
>
> `Improve   - Streamline`
>
> `Straight  - Linear`
>
> `Membrane  - Eardrum`
>
> `Leg       - Drumstick`

The relationship is that:

> the last few letters of each word are the same as the first few letters of the next word.

Comment: At first I was trying to do something similar to that. Where for instance for Jack I tried Black and for following I tried sheep which in order would produce "Black Sheep"... Just my opinion, but the instructions were a little to broad. I probably would have tried to narrow it down so that there was one specific rule to get from list 1 to list 2 (instead of some synonyms some not). I did enjoy trying to find a solution to the puzzle though.

Comment: @Warlord099 Thanks for the feedback.  I didn't want to make things too easy, because I thought if you could figure out 1 or 2 words (especially if they were right next to each other), then the rest of the words would be pretty easy.  It can be hard to find the right balance between too much information and too little information.

Answer (score 1):

Super wildguess here:

> All words have synonyms starting with "S"
> Candy - Sweets
> Jack - Sailor
> Following - Successive/Subsequent
> Territory - Sector/Space/State
> Area - Scope
> Common - Simple
> Improve - Strengthen
> Straight - Straightforward/Square/Straightarrow
> Membrane - Sheath/Sheet
> Leg - Stage
> Also the "**s**ome **s**ort of a relationship" remark

Comment: Not a bad try, but the fact that you have multiple possibilities for some of the words means it's not the perfect answer I'm looking for. I'll also say that none of your words appear in the answer I have in mind.